# how to blend two meshes

Tags: modeling, rendering, mesh, edges

I am a beginner and when I am making a rifle I am using 3 or 4 cubes and then use verts to give it shape but when the rifle is complete, even in the render, it shows separations in the different parts. Like there is a separation between the handle and the top, sort of like lines. How do I make it look like there only one object in the render ?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: To combine all the separate objects into one object, select all the pieces and join them with Ctrl+J. Once they are all one object, select it, enter edit mode, select the whole mesh, then choose `mesh > clean up > merge by distance`. You may need to increase the value in the box that pops up in the corner by a little bit to make sure you connect all the loose verts, but don't increase it too much or you may end up removing unintended vertices. You can see the number of verts removed at the bottom.

Comment: am i doing something wrong im trying but it wont work ? first i press A then i press tab then i go to mesh cleanup and merge vertices but it wont happen am i doing something wrong ? it still looks like two seperate objects im using blender 2.91

Comment: i tried selecting the edges and trying pressing f to fill then but even thats not working

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure then. It's hard to tell without seeing your .blend file, but even that wouldn't help at the moment as I'm not at my home computer and don't currently have access to blender. However, consider uploading your file anyway (or a minimized version) if possible, so that others might have a better chance of helping you. You can do it here - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/